# How do I find the distance between coordinates in QGIS directly from the database

Tags: qgis

I've got a very large database of the coordinates (EPSG:31370) that commuters in Belgium travel to and from (home-work), the coordinate pairs are in the same row. I've placed the 2 pairs of X and Y coordinates onto a map of belgium but how can I find the distance between the pairs in the same rows?

Edit: My issue isn't finding the distance between these points but there are too many points to do by hand, how can I find all the distances at once?

Comment: As it's a projected coordinate system calculating the planimetric distance between two point is a basic use of Pythagorean theorem. If you are looking for other distance you need to edit your question with more detail

Comment: You may use the field calculator to calculate all distance as once (https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html?highlight=calculator#using-the-field-calculator)

Answer (score 2):

Actualy you can solve your problem many ways.
Unit of projection is already meter.
I will try to explain most simplest ways.

**Solution 1**

I guess you already create coordinate pers like StartX, StartY, EndX, EndY...
So you can use hypotenuse teorem in a basic excell sheet.

The formula: =((B2-D2)^2+(C2-E2)^2)^(1/2)
[image]

If you want to get lengths directly in QGIS you can use solution 2.

**Solution 2**

First step you need linestring object, you need the organize your text like this...
[image]

After that you can open this .txt folder with QGIS. You can use "Delimited Text" option.
[image]

Second step you can use Field Calculator in Layer Attribute Table.
Select "$lenght" for Expression.
[image]

You should be seeing all lenghts in the attribute table.

If you have any problem with this solutions please send me an example about your data.

I will try to help about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a virtual layer:

```
select id, st_distance( MakePoint(x1, y1, 31370), MakePoint(x2, y2, 31370)) as distance
from table1
```

(Change x1, y1, x2, y2 and table1 to the names of your fields and layer)

[image]